# Type 'WebAPI.Controllers.ValuesController' does not have a default constructor in Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have started working on ASP.NET Web API but I am new for this technology. here what I have tried to set up my project.

**Step 1** 
Create Web API project 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me that why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Unity.WebAPI` nuget package too. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/using-unity.mvc5-and-unity.webapi-together-in-a-project

Comment: Thank you Milen for your help. In my project I do not have UnityConfig.cs file even after installing Unity.WebAPI nuget package.